# Finding the largest subsets of nodes in a tree subject to some constraints?

Tags: tree, binary-search-tree, graph-algorithm, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

Given a Tree like the following:

```
            X
    /               \
    1               6
/   |   \       /   |   \   
2   5   9       1   5   3
   ...             ...
```

For each node there is a number(except for the root), in the example the numbers are random.

If a node is taken, the next child-node of this node cannot be taken. But the child-child-node is allowed to take. So it's just not okay to take following nodes.

I'm searching for an algorithm which constructs a subset of all nodes which is has maximum amount(the sum of numbers of all taken nodes).
The root has to be taken.

I searched for solutions, I found the red-black-tree which is very similar but not really useful.

Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're trying to solve is called the [maximum independent set problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_set_(graph_theory)) applied to trees.

As a hint, think about the following:

- For each complete subtree of the tree, think about the optimal solution for that subtree in two cases - the case where you include that node in the solution, and the case where you exclude that node from the solution.
- Use dynamic programming: work from the leaves of the tree up to the root of the tree.

Hope this helps!